# Conditional assignment for const reference objects in C++

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, const-reference

Here is a code snippet that illustrates my problem :

```
class A {...};
const A& foo1() {...}
const A& foo2() {...}

void foo3(int score) {
  if (score > 5)
    const A &reward = foo1();
  else 
    const A &reward = foo2();

  ...

  // The 'reward' object is undefined here as it's scope ends within the respective if and else blocks.

}
```

How can I access the `reward` object in `foo3()` after the if else block? This is required to **avoid code duplication**.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `A& reward{condition ? foo1() : foo2()};`

Comment: Use the conditional operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use ternary operator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A

```
const A &reward = (score > 5) ? foo1() : foo2();
```

Comment: Alternatively: `const A &reward = (score > 5 ? foo1 : foo2)();`

Comment: @melpomene: but doesn't support case as `cond ? foo1(42) : foo2("Hi")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) to your advantage. However, you may not use `A& reward = ...` since both `foo1()` and `foo2()` return `const A&`. You will have to use `const A& reward = ...`.

```
const A& reward = ( (score > 5) ? foo1() : foo2() );
```

Comment: @R Sahu Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my question to include const in the assignment operation !

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you may create additional overload:

```
void foo3(const A& reward)
{
    // ...
}

void foo3(int score) {
    if (score > 5)
        foo3(foo1());
    else 
        foo3(foo2());
}
```

Comment: Why go all CPS? If you're going to introduce an extra function, why not just `const A &foo4(int score) { if (score > 5) return foo1(); else return foo2(); } ... void foo3(int score) { const A &reward = foo4(score); ... }`?

Comment: @melpomene: Also possible indeed. Depends how we you to split/expose the code.

Comment: @Jarod42 @melpomene Both the solutions which you presented here are very useful when we have long `if`-`else if`-`else` chain. Using conditional operators in such scenario will definitely make the code ugly. Thanks for your inputs !